# Total counts of columns values exceeds set target remove values dynamically in Powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a huge dataset, this data set are  students records  frequently coming from the web.The column "count" as shown in the image below, will count how many subjects written by each student. As a rule the subjects count shouldnt exceed "2" buh some students have erroneously or deliberately written 3 and more. Please, how can i dynamically remove some selected column values corresponding to a particular StudentID to make the "count" column read 2 instead of manually removing subject scores, which to me will be a huge task and a burden in powerquery

[image]

Comment: Do you actually want to remove columns or remove the values from some columns based on results of Count column? If you want to remove the values from some columns based on the results of Count column on each row, which columns do you want to remove the values from, in order? How is that determined?  Please provide a before and after view of what you want.  Also, don't make us retype the data. Provide numbers

Comment: @horseyride,what i want is whenever  the Total count is greater 3 remove  columns, so that the total counts can adjust to 2

Comment: @horseyride, the removal of columns so that COUNT column values adjust to 2 should be dynamic, because, more subjects or columns are added , this subjects contain scores that tend to increase the count more than the required limits which is "2".How do i do this dynamically?

Comment: This does not answer my question. You need to provide a before/after view of the file showing changes you want to make.  I think you really mean "if the value is 3 then make the value 2" or  "if the value is 3 then erase the value from some <other> column" but you have not specified which you want, or which columns are eligible to be "removed" ? This is why we need an example.  Also, for security reasons, I won't be downloading a file from an external site

Comment: @horseyride, thank you for your response, how do i upload xls files. The platform support only jpeg and image files.  What i want is if the column count exceed 3" delete column cacrs, examcrs ,crs and gradecrs.in this case.

Comment: Please confirm you want to **DELETE** a column, impacting every single row, instead of just removing the **contents** of certain columns.  That sounds very odd.  IF ID=1004 has Count=3 why should I delete a column that impacts all the other IDs? For the before/after view, I would take a JPG, but best case would be to provide your source data as a table embedded in your question

Comment: @horseyride, what i wanted to say, to delete values correspoding to that column not all the columns.IF ID=1004 has Count=3, delete cacrs, examcrs, crs for that ID alone.             Yes  i want to DELETE a column, impacting every single row.

Comment: ..."delete cacrs, examcrs, crs for that ID alone. Yes i want to DELETE a column, impacting every single row" is saying two exact opposite things. You can't delete a column that impacts only that ID alone, if there is a different ID on every row.  I tried one potential solution despite unclear request. If this is not what you are looking for, best of luck with someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
x=  Table.ReplaceValue(Source,  each [cacrs], each if [Count]>2 then null else [cacrs] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"cacrs"}),
x2= Table.ReplaceValue(x,  each [examcrs], each if [Count]>2 then null else [cacrs] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"examcrs"}),
x3= Table.ReplaceValue(x2,  each [crs], each if [Count]>2 then null else [cacrs] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"crs"})
in x3
```

it erases the values in the cacrs, examcrs and crs columns if [Count] on that row >2

[image]

Comment: Thank you @horseyride. I was trying to use this logic to validate students that claim to have register for  a set required number of subjects and went on writing more than the required.   This idea given to me will be very useful to carry out this task.